# If + is associative, prove that +' is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm doing some self-study of elliptic curves and I'm having some difficulty with a problem. Here is the statement:

> Let $S$ be a set with a composition law $\ast$ which has the following two properties
>
> i) $P \ast Q = Q \ast P$ for all $P,Q \in S$
>
> ii) $P \ast (P \ast Q) = Q$ for all $P,Q \in S$.
>
> We define $+'$ to be $P +' Q = \mathcal{O}' \ast (P \ast Q)$ where $\mathcal{O}' \in S$. Assume that $+$ is associative. Prove that $+'$ is associative.

I have earlier proven a result that says that if $+$ is associative then

$R \ast (\mathcal{O} \ast (P \ast Q)) = P \ast (\mathcal{O} \ast (Q \ast R))$ for all $P,Q,R \in S$ and $\mathcal{O} \in S$ is fixed.

Note that $+$ is defined similarly by $P + Q = \mathcal{O} \ast (P \ast Q)$.

I know I need to stem my proof from this previous result but picking a specific $P,Q,R \in S$ which cancels out $\mathcal{O}$ and replaces it with $\mathcal{O}'$ but I'm lost as to how to do this.

Comment: You defined what $+'$ is, but not what $+$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @LordSharktheUnknown !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here goes nothing:

If we assume $+$ to be associative, then we have $R*(O*(Q*P)) = P*(O*(Q*R))$. So means we can swap elements provided there is an $O$ in the correct position.

On the LHS, $R*(O*(Q*P)) = R*(O*(O*(O*(P*Q))) = O*(O*(O*(R*(P*Q)))) = O*(R*(P*Q))$

Here I used (ii) and the associativity of $O$.

Then multiply by $O$ to get $(R*(P*Q))$. Then multiply by $O'$ to get $O'*(R*(P*Q))$. Effectively replacing $O$ by $O'$.

Repeat the steps above to swap $R$ and $O'$ again: $O'*(R*(P*Q)) = O'*(O*(O*(R*(P*Q)))) = R*(O*(O*(O'*(P*Q))) = R*(O'*(Q*P))$

We can do the same steps on the RHS while preserving inequality.

So we get $R*(O'*(Q*P)) = P*(O'*(Q*R))$